# Simulating Drug Entry in Protein and binding?

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, book-recommendation, computational-model, pharmacodynamics

Is there any simulation protocol or paper which can simulate the dynamics of drug entry and  interaction with the target protein?

[image]

Comment: often there is no specific path of diffusion into the active site - it will tend to be a statistical ensemble of possible paths...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tough topic, have a look at the following references and see, if they can help you:

- [Structural modelling and dynamics of proteins for insights into drug
  interactions.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22155026)
- [Ligand entry pathways in the ligand binding domain of PPARγ receptor](http://www.febsletters.org/article/S0014-5793%2811%2900529-1/abstract?cc=y)
- [Pathway and mechanism of drug binding to G-protein-coupled receptors](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/32/13118.long)
- [Molecular Dynamic Simulation and Inhibitor Prediction of Cysteine
  Synthase Structured Model as a Potential Drug Target for
  Trichomoniasis](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/bmri/2013/390920/)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, the two I've had the most success are working with a radiolabeled and a fluorescently labeled version of the drug. Many drugs autofluoresce as well and this can be easily tracked.

When it's labeled as mentioned above microscopy or a luminometer, spectrophomoter or a scintillation counter can evaluate fractions or whole cells, or purified binding substrates.